# Why is RestEasy Quarkus ResponseFilter not getting called after 401 status?

Tags: response, quarkus, resteasy

Hi this is my ResponseFilter:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class ResponseLoggingFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

        if (containerResponseContext.getStatus() != Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {

            switch (containerResponseContext.getStatus()) {
                case 401:
                    // Do something
                    break;
```

The thing is we are using JWT which is automatically evaluated by Quarkus.
Unfortunately when the JWT is invalid my ResponseFilter is not getting called.
So what should happen in case of 401 status code is not executed.

Does anyone know what to do in case of Quarkus and RestEasy ??

Comment: Would an `ExceptionMapper` work?

Comment: No. There is no exception thrown when there is a 401

Comment: ResponseFilter classes generally don't get called when an exception occurs. Are you sure an exception mapper is not being called?

Comment: quite sure. But I found a solution. JWTAuthMechanism